# Proving there is no solution: $-\sin(n\pi \cot^{-1} x)=\sin(n\pi \tan^{-1} x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $n$ be a integer. Prove that this equation has no solutions:
>   $$-\sin(n\pi \cot^{-1} x)=\sin(n\pi \tan^{-1} x)$$

I tried this:
$$-n\pi \cot^{-1} x+k\pi=n\pi \tan^{-1} x, k\in\mathbb{Z}\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{k}{n}= \tan^{-1}x +\cot^{-1}x$$
But $\tan^{-1}x +\cot^{-1}x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, and $\pi$ is irrational, so this is a contradiction, because $k$, $n$ are integers.

> How I can prove this without using that $\pi$ is irrational?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\pi$ were rational. Then you could find solutions to your equation. Hence, solving your problem by other means amounts to proving that $\pi$ is irrational, which is not an easy proof(so I hear). I'm afraid you have the best solution.